# Call two plugin jars in plugin menu

Tags: plugins, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin which is supposed to have a menu with two commands, by clicking on each command we should call the corresponding Plugin, both those Plugins are packaged as jar files.(so command1 calls plugin1.jar and command2 calls plagin2.jar)
How can I implement this? is it even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call the corresponding plugin'? You call methods in classes, which plugin the class is in does not matter provided you set the dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. The basic design of commands in Eclipse allows commands to be defined in any plug-in, and their handlers in any plug-in too (not necessarily the same one even!).

One menu, popup-menu or tool bar within Eclipse can be populated by any plug-in by contributing using the URI mechanism.

I recommend you start with some Eclipse Commands Tutorials, such as http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html so that you can find more specific questions we can help with.